# graphing trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I am so confused on how to graph $$y=\tan^3x-\tan^2x+3\tan{x}-3$$
I already have the graph from wolphram however I don't know how to arrive to such graph. I believe I have to write it as a function $y=A\tan(Bx-C)+D$ but I don't know how. Please help.

Comment: Are we to assume that you want to sketch a graph of this "by hand" rather than use software?

Comment: Yes sir @RoryDaulton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can factor your function as

$$y=(\tan x-1)(\tan^2 x+3)$$

Note that the second factor is never zero, and in fact is always greater than or equal to three. Telling the difference between two large slopes, such as $3$ and $4$, is very difficult for us humans. Therefore your graph will be very similar to the graph of

$$y=3(\tan x-1)$$

You can easily graph that by hand, and there will be almost no practical difference between the graphs. Here are sample graphs from a graphing calculator (TI-Nspire CX):

[image]

It seems clear that your desired graph is not exactly equal to a linearly transformed tangent graph, so I do not see how you could do any better by hand.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to find an equivalent function for it however failed. This is pretty much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...you could factorise it as $$(\tan x-1)(\tan^2x+3)$$ which would indicate the roots etc...

Answer (score 0):

Let $T -$ period of $y$. Then $T=\pi$. Graphing function enough to build $[-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$
$$y=\tan^3x-\tan^2x+3\tan{x}-3$$
$$x\not =\frac{\pi}2+\pi k$$
$$y=\tan^2x(\tan x -1)+3(\tan x-1)$$
$$y=(\tan x -1)(\tan^2x+3)$$
$$y=0; x=\frac{\pi}4+\pi n$$
If $x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\tan x\rightarrow +\infty $, then $y\rightarrow +\infty$;

If $x\rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\tan x\rightarrow -\infty $, then $y\rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: isn't it $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$?

Comment: @marg_ocruz : Oh sure!